# Can I travel to US from India in Dec 2020 on B1/B2 Visa?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, tourist-visas, covid-19

I and my wife have a valid B1/B2 US visa. We intend to travel to US from India in the first week of December 2020 to attend my brothers wedding.

Under the current Covid condition, I am not clear on whether we would be allowed to travel to US on B1/B2 visa? Especially if the reason for the visit is Wedding. I have heard that travel is only allowed for emergencies (death) or for specific scenarios (student). Can someone clarify the same?

Answer (score 0):

There are not (and have not been this year so far) any restrictions on B1 or B2 visitors traveling to the US by air, as long as you have not been physically present in (and don't transit through) Mainland China, Iran, the Schengen Area, the UK, Ireland, or Brazil, in the 14 days before seeking to enter the US. If the rules remain the same in December, you will be able to travel to the US for the wedding.